# Doubly linked list Core dump

Tags: c++, linked-list, coredump

Thanks in advance.

I am making a doubly linked list.

Everything was working fine, but I realized that when I added a new class node somewhere in the middle, the left pointer would still be pointing at the node previously before it (now two spaces away).

So I added a new node pointer on line 46.

Then on line 51 I told that node to now point to the new node.

So :

- First I had new node temp off in space
- Then I make pointer `temp2` loop through the list
- Lastly I tell `temp3` to point to the node after `temp2`'s node

After the function runs, the order should be `temp2->temp->temp3`

**My main point**: After I added line 51, my program core dumps(segmentation fault) and closes out.

How can I fix this? It only happens when I add something that isn't taking place of the head pointer.

```
void add(node *&head, node *&tail, node *&current)
{
    node *temp = new node;  //creates a pointer pointing to a new class node
    cin >> temp->letter;    // user input

    current = head; // creates a pointer to point at the first node
    while (current != NULL) // while list isn't empty
    {
        if (current->letter == temp->letter)
        { // letter already exists
            cout << "DUPLICATE: " << temp->letter << endl << endl;
            return;
        }
        else
        { // loop through list moving tail pointer to the end while checking for duplicates
            tail = current;
            current = current->right_link;
        }
    }

    current = temp; // current = new added node

    if (isEmpty(head))
    { // if first node
        temp->left_link = NULL;
        temp->right_link = NULL;
        head = temp; // head and 
        tail = temp; // tail both point to first and only node.
    }
    else
    { // if new letter value is less than head value
        if(temp->letter < head->letter)
        {
            temp->right_link = head; // node points (right) to head
            temp->left_link = NULL; // left most node point to nothing.
            head->left_link = temp; // head (currently the second node) points (left) to first node
            head = temp; // head pointer moves to the first position
        }
        else
        { // if new node goes anywhere other than head
            node *temp2 = head; // new node to cycle through list
            while(temp2->right_link != NULL && temp2->right_link->letter < temp->letter)
            { // if temp2 points to a node and that node's value is less than temp node value
                temp2 = temp2->right_link;
            }
            node *temp3 = temp2->right_link;
            temp->right_link = temp2->right_link; // when temp2 stops looping, temp will point to
                                                  // the same node as temp2.
            temp2->right_link = temp; // temp2's current node will point to temp, causing temp
                                // to be added into the list (after temp2)
            temp3->left_link = temp; // point the node (after the newly inserted node) left to new node
            temp->left_link = temp2; // connects the left pointer between temp and temp2
            if(temp->right_link == NULL)
                tail = temp;
        }
    }
    cout << "ADDED : " << temp->letter << endl << endl;
}
```

Comment: Could you post an [mcve]? also, did you try using a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

if `temp2->right_link == NULL`

```
 46      node *temp3 = temp2->right_link;
```

is a NULL pointer, so you can't

```
 51      temp3->left_link = temp;
```

which should have been obvious if you used a debugger.

Comment: It totally should have been obvious, thanks for the help. I will look for whatever this debugger stuff is that everyone is talking about.